# Unable to click on Sign In button through xpath & AndroidUIAutomator

Tags: xpath, appium

[image]I am unable to click on sign in button in mobile using Appium.

I have used xpath & androidUiAutomator but unable to succeed.
Following are the details:

For Xpath i used: 
//android.widget.TextView[@text='Sign In']

For AndroidUiAutimator i used:
return driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("text(\"Sign In\")");

```
public void MainLogin() throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Enter in Epcl_MainLogin");
        TouchAction touch=new TouchAction(driver);
        WebDriverWait wt=new WebDriverWait(driver,20);
        LoginPom objLogin = new LoginPom(driver);
        wt.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(objLogin.LoginName()));
        objLogin.LoginName().sendKeys("Testa");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(2);
        driver.hideKeyboard();
        objLogin.LoginPassword().sendKeys("Testb");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(4);
        driver.hideKeyboard();
        objLogin.BtnLogin().click();
        System.out.println("Button Clicked Successfully");
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(8);
        System.out.println("Login Successfully");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add **content-description** to your sign in button (in your android code). Then you will be able to click the button by using

```
driver.findElementByAccessibilityId("your content description").click()
```

You can also add id to your button and click it using:

```
driver.findElementById("you button id").click();
```

> Using xpath in appium is not recommended

Comment: Ok Thanks. Let me ask developers to do that and get back to you.

Comment: Thanks @Suban :)
Sorry for the late response.
It works for me as you suggest. Thanks alot. :)